# I am not able to view Content type hub in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Hey I have created a new SharePoint online tenant from below URL `"https://signup.microsoft.com/Signup?OfferId=B07A1127-DE83-4a6d-9F85-2C104BDAE8B4&dl=ENTERPRISEPACK&culture=en-IN&country=IN&alo=1".`

Till yesterday whenever I created new account I was able to access content type hub.

But today when I created new tenant i was not able to access content type hub(`"https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/sites/contenttypehub"`). I tried creating couple of times but issue still persist.

Could any of you please help me.

Comment: Do you get any error or message while accessing the link?

Comment: you probably need to wait for few mins. Try accessing it after sometime, it will be there

Comment: The error shown was "404 file not found".

Comment: I tried after an hour still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that the page is not found.

Have you deleted the home page?

Have somebody deleted the content type hub site?

Make sure you have permission on the content type hub site in SharePoint online.

Check whether you can access to the other pages instead  of home page, try to access to other pages.